# Deploying assemblies to the bin folder without adding references to the project

Tags: .net, build

I am heavily using dependency injection in my application.  As such, my components reference interfaces, and the concrete implementations are known only to my IoC container, configured through XML files.

A consequence of this design is that I end up needing assemblies in my bin folder (e.g. Newtonsoft.Json, SqlLite) that I have no need to reference in my project.  In fact, I explictly **do not want** references, as I or my team may accidentally refer to a concrete implementation rather than an interface, thereby destroying the advantages of the DI we're using.

The _bin_DeployableAssemblies folder introduced in VS 2010 SP1 was useful for this scenario, but applied only to [web projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389506/why-is-the-bin-deployableassemblies-folder-specific-to-web-applications) (I'm personally using MVC3 and ok with that, but it doesn't solve the general problem.  However, it appears to be more or less [deprecated in VS11 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587355/is-visual-studio-11-beta-missing-the-add-deployable-assemblies-menu-option).  [Copying the files into the bin directory prior to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712162/asp-net-and-visual-studio-adding-project-references-vs-bin-folder-dll) feels icky - the bin folder is no longer a container for build artifacts.  I suppose a custom post-build event could be used, but it seems there should be something more "out of the box" to solve this problem.  Am I stuck with post-build?  What other ways are there to tackle this issue?

Comment: You are looking at a world of hurt by not including dependencies. If you want to reference abstract types do that. You can enforce that using static analysis tools like nDepend.

Comment: @Oded, what's the world of hurt you're talking about.  How could this cause problems?

Comment: @LandonPoch - Deployment issues mostly, though the logistics of configuring the IoC container when one doesn't have references to concrete classes comes to mind as well (especially if you want strongly typed configuration). I have seen the above approach blow up on deployment as the IoC container could not find the configured concrete dependencies (the were not referenced _anywhere_ so not deployed).

Comment: @Oded, I have used Ninject modules that are dynamically loaded on app start and as long as the DLLs are in the bin it has not given me problems about not being able to find the concrete types.  I like omitting the references because it helps enforce decoupling, especially if you have junior developers that are working on your team.

Comment: "as long as the DLLs are in the bin" - that's the key. As for - "if you have junior developers that are working on your team" - you teach them instead of using technical tools to avoid teaching them.

Comment: @Oded, I agree teaching them is key.  I heavily invest in developers on my team (some might say too much).  I will say though that enforcement goes a long way on a large team with mostly juniors when things get fast and furious on a project.  You can almost compare this to why the private keyword exists in many languages... enforces smaller scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle this:

1. A post-build event to copy the files into the bin folder will handle this.
2. Include the files *as content items* in the Project, but not as references.  They can be set to copy to the output folder on build.

I sometimes use the second option.  This does have the advantage of keeping the "dependency" obvious to developers, while still preventing them from actually using the types defined within the assemblies, as they are not references and the compiler will not see them as available.

Comment: Doesn't the second option copy into the bin folder based on a path relative to the source file?  In other words, to get them directly in bin, don't I have to shove these things into the the root application directory rather than a ~/lib folder?

Comment: @EmilLerch Yes, pretty much - however, I just configure my DI to look for them in the ./lib folder, since it'll copy into bin\Debug\Lib if you put them in a Lib folder in your project...

Comment: worked just fine. I added the <probing> element (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx) and the framework looks in the right folder