# Where should I store referenced DLL binaries in my visual studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, reference

When writing programs (C#.NET) I'll commonly use external libraries I've downloaded from various websites such as custom WinForm controls, or other libraries. Even if the source is available I usually prefer to reference the compiled DLL files rather then create another whole project in my solution for the 3rd party library or control.

So my question is where would people typically store external DLLs like this in the solution? The referencing project folder? The solution folder? Another folder?

Comment: I think this answers it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868451

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always create a lib folder at the same level of the src folder and put all external DLLs there. They are referenced through a relative path.

Comment: At the depth of the project or solution? Or does it depend on if the library is used across multiple projects in the solution?

Comment: +1 I do the same, I create the folder in the same folder the `.sln` is in.

Comment: You can imagine having a lib folder per project, for 3rd party stuff specific to a project, and a lib folder for the solution for "global" dependencies, but I don't think it's worth it to be this granular. I guess most dependencies will start at the project level, then will have to migrate to the solution level because this 3rd party DLL gets to be used by more than one project.